# Filtering rows based on dynamic column count & column name in R

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I am having a data frame named `inputDf` which have the binary values in all the columns other than `Rating` column.

```
inputDf <- structure(list(Q1 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Q2 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Q3 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), Q4 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Q5 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Q6 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), 
Q7 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Q8 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Q9 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L
), Q10 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Q11 = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Q12 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L), Rating = c(7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 5L), RatingBinary = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), row.names = c(13L, 17L, 26L, 
71L, 72L, 55L, 56L, 69L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am having another similar data frame named `combinationDf`

```
combinationDf <- structure(list(Q1 = c(0L, 0L), Q2 = c(0L, 0L), Q3 = 1:0, Q4 = c(1L, 
1L), Q5 = c(0L, 0L), Q6 = c(0L, 0L), Q7 = c(0L, 0L), Q8 = c(0L, 
0L), Q9 = c(0L, 0L), Q10 = c(0L, 0L), Q11 = c(1L, 1L), Q12 = 0:1), row.names = 1:2, class = 
"data.frame")
```

The problem statement is for every combination of 1's in each row in `combinationDf`, I need to filter rows from `inputDf`

I implemented the logic by hard-coding the number of columns to be considered for filtering out the data.

```
    finalDf <- data.frame() 
    for(i in 1:nrow(combinationDf)){
      ind <- which(combinationDf[i,] == 1)
      ind <- paste("Q",ind, sep = "")
      sample <- inputDf %>%
        dplyr::filter(eval(parse(text=ind[1])) == 1 & eval(parse(text=ind[2])) == 1 & eval(parse(text=ind[3])) == 1) %>%
        as.data.frame()
      finalDf <<- rbind(finalDf,sample)
    }
```

However, I'm looking for the general code to filter out the data using N # of columns. i.e, the above code works for filtering using 3 columns. If I need to filter based on 4 columns, I need to add a condition. To overcome that, I used the code below,

```
  sample <- inputDf %>%
    dplyr::filter(as.logical(paste(paste0("eval(parse(text = ind[", 1:length(ind), "])) == 1"), collapse = " & "))) %>%
    as.data.frame()
```

This snippet doesn't filter the rows as expected. Can anyone point me out the mistake I have done in the above code? Or can provide the best approach to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may make sense to subset and then do a semi join for filtering

```
finalDf <- data.frame() 
for(i in 1:nrow(combinationDf)){
  sample <- inputDf %>%
    semi_join(combinationDf %>% slice(i) %>% select(where(~.x==1)))
  finalDf2 <- rbind(finalDf ,sample)
}
```

At each loop iteration we select all the columns that are 1 and then just join to extract the matching values from `inputDf`. This will work with any number of columns. Another way of expressing this without the loop in `dplyr` is

```
combinationDf %>% 
  group_by(id=1:n()) %>% 
  group_map(~.x %>% 
    select(where(~.x==1)) %>% 
    semi_join(inputDf, .)
  ) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

This may be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Base R approach :

- Use `apply` in rowwise fashion to go through each row in `combinationDf`.
- Get the column names which has value as 1 in a row.
- Subset those columns in `inputDf` and select rows where all the values are 1.
- Combine the list of dataframes into one dataframe.

```
result <- do.call(rbind, apply(combinationDf, 1, function(x) 
           inputDf[rowSums(inputDf[names(x)[x == 1]] != 1) == 0, ]))
rownames(result) <- NULL
result

#   Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5 Q6 Q7 Q8 Q9 Q10 Q11 Q12 Rating RatingBinary
#1   0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   0   1   1      7            1
#2   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1      7            1
#3   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   0   1   1      6            1
#4   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1      5            0
#5   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1      6            1
#6   0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   0   1   1      7            1
#7   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1      7            1
#8   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   0   1   1      6            1
#9   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1      5            0
#10  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1      6            1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
combinationDf %>% 
  apply(1, function(x) paste0(names(inputDf)[x == 1], "==1", collapse = "&")) %>%
  lapply(function(x) filter(inputDf, eval(parse(text = x)))) %>%
  Reduce(rbind, .)
```